# How to create log `csv` file. Which contain a filename corresponding with link

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-requests, logfile

I have list of `urls` in csv file which contain `urls` something like this :

```
manual_name1  12344.pdf #pdf link
manual_name2  12334.pdf #pdf link
```

After running a code which is mention below. Downloaded File will save as:
`manual_name1.pdf` and `manual_name2.pdf` and so on.

I want a `csv` log file which contain name of pdf file  corresponding from where its is downloaded. like this in following example

```
manual_name.pdf   12344.pdf #pdflink
manual_name2.pdf  12334.pdf #pdflink
```

Here is following code:

```
import os
import csv
import requests
import time


write_path = '/Users/macossierra/Desktop/pdf'  # ASSUMING THAT FOLDER EXISTS!


with open('this.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for link in spamreader:
        if not link:
            continue
        print('-'*72)
        pdf_file = '{}_{}.pdf'.format(link[0], int(time.time())) 
        with open(os.path.join(write_path, pdf_file), 'wb') as pdf:
            try:
                # Try to request PDF from URL
                print('Trying To Connect with Link>>>>>.          {}...'.format(link[1]))
                a = requests.get(link[1], stream=True)
                for block in a.iter_content(512):
                    if not block:
                        break

                    pdf.write(block)
                print('File Downloaded Successfully.')
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  # This will catch ONLY Requests exceptions
                print('REQUESTS ERROR:')
                print(e)  # This should tell you more details about the error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need formatting similar to what you listed above, you could simply write out a row to CSV as soon as the PDF file is downloaded.

```
import os
import csv
import requests
import time

write_path = '/Users/macossierra/Desktop/pdf'  # ASSUMING THAT FOLDER EXISTS!

with open('this.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    with open('log.csv', 'wb') as csv_out:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_out)
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for link in spamreader:
            if not link:
                continue
            print('-'*72)
            pdf_file = '{}_{}.pdf'.format(link[0], int(time.time()))
            with open(os.path.join(write_path, pdf_file), 'wb') as pdf:
                try:
                    # Try to request PDF from URL
                    print('Trying to connect with link >>>>> {} ... '.format(link[1]))
                    a = requests.get(link[1], stream=True)
                    for block in a.iter_content(512):
                        if not block:
                            break
                        pdf.write(block)
                    print('File downloaded successfully.')
                    path = os.path.join(write_path, pdf_file)
                    writer.writerow([pdf_file, link[1], path, str(time.time())]) # writing content to our CSV log file
                except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:  # This will catch ONLY Requests exceptions
                    print('REQUESTS ERROR:')
                    # This should tell you more details about the error log
                    print(e)
```